# Save many-to-many field on object create - Django DRF

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

Pardon me if this is an obvious question. I've searched different answers but they don't answer my specific case.

I have a model that has a many-to-many field relationship. When I create a new object via DRF rest API, the normal fields of the object (model) are saved correctly but the many-to-many related field remains empty.

My model with the many-to-many related field:

```
class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Store) # <- the related field
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name)
```

The related (store) model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    ...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.store_name)
```

My serializer:

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = StoreSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerProfile
        fields = ['stores', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']
```

My view:

```
class CustomerCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = CustomerProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

My post:

```
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: this.api_base_url + "api/.../customer_create/",
    data: {
        first_name: 'Tom',
        last_name: 'Hardy',
        email: 'name@gmail.com',
        phone: '01234567898',
        stores: ['store_name',], // this is the store I want to link the customer to
    }
})
```

When I post to this endpoint, an object is created but the `stores` array is always empty.

Results:

```
data:
  email: "name@gmail.com"
  first_name: "Tom"
  last_name: "Hardy"
  phone: "08038192642"
  stores: []
```

What is the right way to add the stores?

Comment: Are the stores objects already created, i.e. you can relate them by id, or do you want to create new store objects?

Comment: @iserranoe yes they are already created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Store.objects.all(), write_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerProfile
        fields = ['stores', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']
```

Comment: I get ```400 (Bad Request)```

Comment: Would you specify the exact error? Also are you getting the same fields as mentioned here?

Comment: In this case, you must post the id's, exemple: "stores: [154, 26]" Otherwise, you should define the field store_name as primary_field.

Comment: It might be better to see the data in postman or insomnia. It would be easy to debug then. This might help https://medium.com/@kingsleytorlowei/building-a-many-to-many-modelled-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-d41f54fe372

Comment: I got it working now. I had to use the store ID as @iserranoe suggested